# The shortest js redirect?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write a redirect using Javascript if I have only have space for 32 chars, including the URL and the `<script></script>` tags?
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: 32 chars including or excluding the URL?

Comment: Edited topic information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if your URL is 21 characters or shorter:

```
location='up to 21 chars in URL'
```

For example:

```
location='http://google.com'
```

This works because `location` is a property of `window`, and all properties of `window` are global variables. Assigning a URL string to `location` takes the browser there.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/abumit/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/abumit/1/edit)

You can use any of several URL-shortening services ([bit.ly](http://bit.ly), [goo.gl](http://goo.gl), etc.) to keep your URL short enough.

If you know that the protocol of the page you're redirecting from is acceptable for the redirect, you can save five characters:

```
location='//google.com'
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/abumit/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/abumit/2/edit)

If the page you're on starts with `http:`, that will take you to `http://google.com`; if it starts with `https:`, that will take you to `https://google.com`. Etc. [Details](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html)